# How to get unique elements from vector using stl?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector of strings. For now take:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string>{
"one","two","three","two","ten","six","ten".......
}
```

Now I want to filter out only unique strings in the vector, and in the same order as they are.

Is there a standard library function for this?

EDIT: I need to discard the repeated values.

Comment: So you don't want to sort your vector ?

Comment: [`std::unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

Comment: @DrewDormann {"B"} is preserving the same order as "A" is repeated and must be discarded.

Comment: @paolo  No, I don't want to sort it.

Comment: Or create a std::set from your vector

Comment: @PepijnKramer I don't think `std::set` will keep the original order of the elements, if they're not sorted.

Comment: @paolo No it will not keep the order so that was not a good answer from me

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with DSA (digital signature algorithm).

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to add data, structure and algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the duplicate while keeping the order of the elements, you can do it (inplace) in `O(n log(n))` like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{"one", "two", "three", "two",  "ten", "six", "ten"};

// Occurrence count
std::map<std::string, int> m;

auto it = std::copy_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), v.begin(),
                       [&m](std::string const& s) { return !m[s]++; });
                    // ^ keep s if it's the first time I encounter it

v.erase(it, v.end());
```

Explanation: `m` keeps track of the number of times each string has already been encountered while scanning through `v`. The `copy_if` won't copy a string if it has already been found.

---

If you want to remove all the elements that are duplicated, you can do it (inplace) in `O(n log(n))` like this:

```
// Occurrence count
std::map<std::string, int> m;

// Count occurrences of each string in v
std::for_each(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [&m](std::string const& s) { ++m[s]; } );

// Only keep strings whose occurrence count is 1.
auto it = std::copy_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), v.begin(),
                       [&m](std::string const& s) { return m[s] == 1; });
v.erase(it, v.end());
```

Comment: Why map? Using unordered_map here will give you the same result but much better performance close to O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a frequency map from the `vector` and create a new `vector` including only the elements with a frequency of 1.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> v{"one", "two", "three", "two", "ten", "six", "ten"};
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> freq;
for(const auto& e: v) ++freq[e];
std::vector<std::string> res;
res.reserve(v.size());
for (const auto& e: v)
    if (freq[e] == 1) res.push_back(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will count the occurrences of each string and erase elements with more than one occurrence.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> m;
for ( auto & s : v ) ++m[s];

std::erase_if( v, [&](auto const &s){ return m[s] > 1;} );
```

The entire operation is O(n).

[See it work in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xWdWrsYPr)

Comment: How can it be `O(n)` ? You have a `O( log (n) )` lookup in the map for each of the `n` elements of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
std::vector<std::string> unique(const std::vector<std::string> &original)
{
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  std::set<std::string> aux;
  for (auto it = original.begin(); it != original.end(); ++it) {
    if(aux.find(*it) == aux.end()){
      aux.insert(*it);
      result.push_back(*it);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

It will keep the order of the original input vector:

output:

```
one
two
three
ten
six
```